# Video js not working as expected with angular and FF

Tags: angularjs, html, firefox, video

I need to create site with video which have autoplay and depend on profile which user selected. So in angular i created template popupVideo:

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
       controls autoplay preload="auto" height="100%" width="100%">
  <source ng-repeat="vidObj in fullScreenVideoUrl" src="{{vidObj.url}}" type="{{vidObj.type}}"/>
  <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

Then in controller i have code:

```
function showPopupVideo() {
        $scope.fullScreenVideoUrl = [];
        var webm = {};
        webm.url = $scope.currentProfile.video_full + ".webm";
        webm.type = "video/webm";
        $scope.fullScreenVideoUrl.push(webm);
        var mp4 = {};
        mp4.url = $scope.currentProfile.video_full + ".mp4";
        mp4.type = "video/mp4";
        $scope.fullScreenVideoUrl.push(mp4);
        var ogg = {};
        ogg.url = $scope.currentProfile.video_full + ".ogv";
        ogg.type = "video/ogg";
        $scope.fullScreenVideoUrl.push(ogg);
        ngDialog.open({
          template: 'scripts/contents/template/popupVideo.html',
          className: 'popup-fullscreen',
          scope: $scope
        });
      }
```

So all work fine in Chrome and IE, window opens video starts and playing.
But in FF all going wrong, when window opened first time, it started to download (according to network monitor) but NO autoplay, also in console i could see:

```
Specified "type" attribute of "{{vidObj.type}}" is not supported. Load of media resource {{vidObj.url}} failed. localhost:3000
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused. localhost:3000
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

However! If i press play it start playing video!

Then if i close this window and open again, it show in console same text about not supported, BUT now it started to play video and in same time show on it text that "No video with supported format and MIME type found" how is it possible??? It cant find and it playing it in same time...

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late but what you need to do is use ng-src="{{vidObj.url}}" instead of src="{{vidObj.url}}"